# Docker-Compose: Can't connect to Redis Service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, docker-container

I'm working on dockerizing an app but got stuck on a problem with redis. It seems my app does not want to connect to the redis container and I'm not sure why.

Repo: https://github.com/plecco/lempdock

Working on "Irfan" branch

The screenshots below show my .env config and the results.

Help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should post text, not screenshots. If you are able to, please edit the question and replace the relevant images with text (in this case, the first and third image)

Answer (score 0):

You are using here `REDIS_HOST=lempdock_redis_1` which leads me to believe that you're using docker-compose with a project name of `lempdock`. In that case you will find the container name is `lempdock_redis_1`, but you can't reach the Redis service using that as a hostname.

Change your configuration so that the expected hostname for Redis is simply `redis`.

In docker-compose (or in Swarm), the name you use for your service in the docker-compose.yml file is also used as its DNS name. So that's the name you should tell your other containers to connect to.